# How to modify this batch to continuously work?

Tags: batch-file

My friend wants to run this batch 24 hours. So basically it pings and print time

```
    @echo off

set/p host=host Address: 
set logfile=Log_%host%.log
echo Target Host = %host% >%logfile%
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('ping %host% -n 1 ') do (echo %%A>>%logfile% && GOTO Ping)
:Ping
for /f "tokens=* skip=2" %%A in ('ping %host% -n 1 ') do (
    echo %date% %time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2% %%A>>%logfile%
    echo %date% %time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2% %%A
    timeout 1 >NUL    
    GOTO Ping)
```

He told me that when the ping time out the program stops. This is not desired. He wants the program to keep running and log the time it's out.

How to modify it?

Comment: I see no reason for it to not work in its current form, but tell your friend to try moving `GOTO Ping` outside of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

This logs response time greater than 100 ms. Adapt as you will.

```
:loop
    wmic /append:"textfile.txt" path win32_pingstatus where "address='127.0.0.1' and responsetime > 100" get responsetime,timestamprecord
    timeout /t 5
goto loop
```

It's a **bad idea** to put `GoTo` into `for` loops.

See `wmic /?`, `wmic path win32_pingstatus get /?` for help..

Comment: A `goto` inside a `for` loop is okay if you're using it to abruptly terminate the loop. Labels, on the other hand, should always be avoided inside of loops.